# Prestashop: How to add own row after attribute size?

Tags: php, html, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I need to add my own row after between attributes in my product page (in prestashop). After "size" in my case is a attribute_label, group_5 "Size" -> after that attribute to add something like: "Find your size here in our guide."

To add this code:

```
<p class="find">Find your size in our guide <a href="htttp://bijutaniki.com/#">here</a></p>
```

Final look need to be like:

[image]

In product.tpl look like:

```
            <div class="product_attributes">
            {if isset($groups)}
            <!-- attributes -->
            <div id="attributes">
            <div class="clear"></div>
            {foreach from=$groups key=id_attribute_group item=group}
                {if $group.attributes|@count}
                    <fieldset class="attribute_fieldset">
                        <label class="attribute_label" for="group_{$id_attribute_group|intval}">{$group.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'} :&nbsp;</label>
                        {assign var="groupName" value="group_$id_attribute_group"}
                        <div class="attribute_list">
                        {if ($group.group_type == 'select')}
                            <select name="{$groupName}" id="group_{$id_attribute_group|intval}" class="attribute_select" onchange="findCombination();getProductAttribute();">
                                {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
                                    <option value="{$id_attribute|intval}"{if (isset($smarty.get.$groupName) && $smarty.get.$groupName|intval == $id_attribute) || $group.default == $id_attribute} selected="selected"{/if} title="{$group_attribute|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}">{$group_attribute|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</option>
                                {/foreach}
                            </select>
                        {elseif ($group.group_type == 'color')}
                            <ul id="color_to_pick_list" class="clearfix">
                                {assign var="default_colorpicker" value=""}
                                {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
                                <li{if $group.default == $id_attribute} class="selected"{/if}>
                                    <a id="color_{$id_attribute|intval}" class="color_pick{if ($group.default == $id_attribute)} selected{/if}" style="background: {$colors.$id_attribute.value};" title="{$colors.$id_attribute.name}" onclick="colorPickerClick(this);getProductAttribute();">
                                        {if file_exists($col_img_dir|cat:$id_attribute|cat:'.jpg')}
                                            <img src="{$img_col_dir}{$id_attribute}.jpg" alt="{$colors.$id_attribute.name}" width="20" height="20" /><br />
                                        {/if}
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                {if ($group.default == $id_attribute)}
                                    {$default_colorpicker = $id_attribute}
                                {/if}
                                {/foreach}
                            </ul>
                            <input type="hidden" class="color_pick_hidden" name="{$groupName}" value="{$default_colorpicker}" />
                        {elseif ($group.group_type == 'radio')}
                            <ul>
                                {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
                                    <li>
                                        <input type="radio" class="attribute_radio" name="{$groupName}" value="{$id_attribute}" {if ($group.default == $id_attribute)} checked="checked"{/if} onclick="findCombination();getProductAttribute();" />
                                        <span>{$group_attribute|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</span>
                                    </li>
                                {/foreach}
                            </ul>
                        {/if}
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                {/if}
            {/foreach}
            </div>
        {/if}
```

Comment: What is your question? You know where to put it, you know what to put there..

Comment: If you want it where you put it in the console, then almost down at the bottom, just beneath `</fieldset>` is where you would put it.

Comment: No. If i put it there new code shows after every attribute. I can see it live here: http://bijutaniki.com/prysteni/8-prysten-na-nastroenieto.html

I want to show this code only after size (размер in bulgarian).

Comment: Then try in between the `{if}` statement for `{if ($group.group_type == 'select')}`. This will however do it for all dropdown attributes. So if you have more, you need to create another IF that checks for `size`

Comment: I have more dropdown attributes on some products. So i need to add other "if" for group_5 (size in my case) how is right way to add it - excuse me for this stuped qustion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ($group.name == 'Size'} conditional. add it under `group.type == select` conditional.

```
{if ($group.name == 'Size')}
 <p class="find">Find your size in our guide <a href="htttp://bijutaniki.com/#">here</a></p>
{/if}
```

Change 'Size' the attribute you have another name.